# Tengo un problema al Crear un Proyecto Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm, cli

Estoy usando Windows 7 (32 Bits), tengo instalado Node.js, NPM y la Cli de Angular. al momento de crear un proyecto a través del comando ng new NombreProyectoAngular comienza todo bien, pero luego de descargar todo el contenido muestra una cantidad de errores los cuáles les enseño en las imágenes. Ya probé desinstalando todo desde raíz, borrando todas las carpetas del disco duro e instalando todo desde cero pero siempre sucede lo mismo. todos los comandos los ejecuto como administrador, ya no se que mas intentar. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano. [image: Comienzo de la Instalación]

[image: Al finalizar]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta última foto muestra el nuevo error que me aparece luego de instalar Python 2.7

Comment: Descarga de nuevo el npm e instálalo.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho pero los errores continúan. instalé python versión 2.7 y ya no me muestra errores sobre python pero ahora aparecen los de la 3ra foto que acabo de subir, ahoa estoy descargando el .Net Framework 2.0 SDK a ver que sucede.

Comment: Bueno comentanos si te resultó, saludos.